# Code Beautifier of Code Review is better than Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, design

This is a suggestion for Stack Overflow Code Block.

The style of the code blocks on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is much more decent as compared to that is being using in Stack Overflow.

Is there any good reason for not changing Stack Overflow's code style?

Comment: [so] uses [Google Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)...  I feel that it works great!  Is there any specific thing you don't like about it?  Perhaps it is just confusion about a certain feature... What exactly do you not like about it?

Comment: @Lix I take the OP is referring to the CSS styles used for the highlighted code, but maybe he doesn't effectively know Stack Exchange is using the same software for all the sites.

Comment: @cod - Saying that *you* don't like it is not really a good enough reason to change something.  Perhaps you can be more specific?

Comment: Actually I meant to say the CSS used in Code Review is neat and compact, whereas in StackOveflow it consumes more space and is not neat also.

Comment: @Lix I know it very well that it won't change on my choice.

Comment: Here's my guess:

Most CR posts have large hunks of code. This can easily drown out the text, so the style is more muted.

On the other hand, SO usually doesn't have large hunks of code, but the code is pretty important--hence it is more prominent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, Code Review [looks better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ8cz.png) [than SO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KCR9.png) too.

[image: Inline code on Code Review]

Also, I like the `inline code` better, with the whitespace between lines, [unlike Stack Overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORsn8.png),
`where lines blend into each other`.

Answer (score 4):

It's funny that you'd say this. For me (Chrome on OS X) the style on Code Review is more spread out and harder to read compared to what's used on SO. Here's codereview:

[image: codereview screenshot]

and here's SO:

[image: stackoverflow screenshot]

(Images might be scaled when viewing on the mobile site.)

As you (hopefully) see, the lines on codereview are farther apart, yet the type is smaller. This means more scrolling, and more eyestrain. I can't see how either of these aspects are better, frankly.

Comment: Where did you view this? Your images were 770 pixels wide (and on the regular site than shown scaled to 640), where the main content area on these sites is 650 pixels. On my OS X on a MacBook Air, I like [Code Review's rendering](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ8cz.png) better than [that on SO](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7KCR9.png).

Comment: SO's code window looks ugly to me.